# Enumerate subsection, but don't print at TOC

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering, bookmarks

what I try to achieve is the following: I want all subsections in the appendix have 'normal' numbers (as they currently have), but I don't want them to be displayed in the TOC. When using \subsection*{}, they are not displayed in the TOC but neither have they numbers...

Further, if possible: It would though still be nice if they are included in the TOC of the PDF-Viewer (in contrast to the TOC which is really 'printed')
Thanks!

**EDIT**: Can't get your suggestion to work Tobi:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{bla}
\section{blipp}
\subsection{blupp}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}% number \part and \chapter in book classes
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{-1}% “delete” lowest level from TOC 
\appendix
\chapter{appch}
\section{secasdasd}
\subsection{asd}
\section{secasdfasd}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT2**: @Gonzalo: Since I was asking for a working example for subsectioning, I just modified your *WORKING* Example for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=subsection]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection one}

\appendix
\chapter{Test Appendix}
\settocdepth{section}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\section{Test section one}
\subsection{Test subsection one}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for providing it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\settocdepth` from the `tocvsec2` package to change the value of `tocdepth` just for the appendix; for the bookmarks, you can set the `bookmarksdepth` option from `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocvsec2}
\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=section]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section one}
\appendix
\chapter{Test Appendix}
\settocdepth{chapter}
\section{Test section one}
\section{Test section one}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will also exclude them from the PDF-toc. But thanks though, this is better than nothing, the PDF-TOC isn't that important!

Comment: @Marc Edlo: See my answer which provides everything you need, I guess …

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely! Provided small editioned version above just to match my exact question!

Answer (score 4):

You can change the counters `secnumdepth` and/or `tocdepth`—even in the document, i. e. befor `\appendix`

`secnumdepth` controls which section levels get a number and
`tocdepth` says which go to the TOC

Examples:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}% number \part and \chapter in book classes
\addtocounter{tocdepth}{-1}% “delete” lowest level from TOC
```

I don’t know a way of changing the PDF-TOC seperatly but have a look at `hyperref` and it’s manual.

### Update

`hyperref` has an option `bookmarksdepth` for setting the depth of PDF-TOC

Edit: Here is an example showing all of the above mentioned solutions:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=2]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{bla}
\section{blipp}
\subsection{blupp}

\appendix
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

\chapter{appch}
\section{secasdasd}
\subsection{asd}
\section{secasdfasd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't get it to work, see above! Edit: The example isn't completely related since it doesn't change things for the APPENDIX ONLY!

Comment: @Marco Edlo: I’m sorry, Thought I used it in this was earlyer. I changed my example so it should work now. The problem was (is) that `tocdepth` is evaluated in `\tableofcontents` only so we have to put it to the `toc`-file with `\addcontents`.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks to you too, this works also pretty well :) It's a pity I can't accept two answers ;)